# How to fetch data from API in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, rxjs

I am trying to fetch data from API on my localhost server using "Axios" in React Native but I am stuck that how can i do This is my react code that same i have to convert in react native

```
export function blog(props){
const posts = useAPI ('/api/posts');
return (
<ul>
{posts?.data && 
posts.data.map((post) => (
<li>
{posts.name}
</li>
))
}
);
}
```

export default blog;

Comment: It's the same like reactjs. Take a look at this article: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-axios-react-native-manage-api-requests/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a proper API endpoint

like your localhost 
`localhost:8080/api/posts`
then you have use like this
1: Know your IP address (192.168.1.1)

you can get IP address in cmd in windows: ipconfig
you can get IP address in System Preference/Networ/Selected Network / Info in mac

2: Your endpoint will be look like this
http://192.168.1.1/api/posts

**Notes:**
Yours device and system should be on same network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).